# Stuck: Problems moving Wordpress site from Sub Domain to Root Directory w/ Host Gator

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ftp, subdomain

I am attempting to move my Wordpress website from the subdomain where it is installed:
**chicagokaraokenight[dot]com/wordpress**

to the root directory:
**chicagokaraokenight[dot]com**

I've been following the instructions provided by this [website](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-safely-move-wordpress/?nlv=c&utm_expid=3606929-32.jVSGECWYSiWZJXI3ODEEGA.2).

So, I've:
1) backed up the site
2) I didn't have a site in the root directory but I deleted any redirects I was using
3) turned permalinks to default
4) changed the site address (left the first as /wordpress and changed the second)
5) Downloaded the index.php and .htaccess files, and changed the index.php file to

```
contains require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Finished up by uploading, changed back permalinks to the previous settings, and now it's not working. I am assuming I took a misstep when downloading/editing/uploading the files, since the other parts were so self explanatory. After tinkering with it, I'm a little confused what it looked like before and what it should look like now, and it's still not working. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

At the moment, when I go to either URL (root or sub), I am getting the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' );' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /home2/lsaewitz/public_html/index.php on line 17**

Currently, both directories (public_html AND wordpress) have both an index.php file and an .htaccess file, and both index.php files have the edits made in step #5 above.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

One thing I did notice, is that between a couple different tutorials, some index.php files had:

```
contains require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

and others just had:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

without the *require('./wp-blog-header.php');* part

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Looking over the tutorial, looks like the places where you change index.php is missing a closing quote around every string such as: `require ('./wp-blog-header.php)` should be `require ('./wp-blog-header.php')` <--closing quote after string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Don't I have that closing quote above? >> contains require( dirname( FILE ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' ); >>. All I did to edit was at /wordpress, so no quotes were deleted.

Comment: Perhaps it is the "curly quote"? If you look at what was posted here you can see it. If that line was copy/pasted from the source, that would be the issue. Try swapping it out for a normal single quote. A lot of blogs and programs like word and outlook like to swap quotes out for curly ones which are not really "quotes" as far as programming is concerned.

Comment: That worked!! I'm guessing what happened is when I edited in TextEditor vs. the FTP Manager it used a "curly quote". Thank you @JonathanKuhn!!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn do you want to add that as answer so I can mark it as correct? or do I do it? i'm a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is the "curly quote"? If you look at what was posted here you can see it. If that line was copy/pasted from the source, that would be the issue. Try swapping it out for a normal single quote. A lot of blogs and programs like word and outlook like to swap quotes out for curly ones which are not really "quotes" as far as programming is concerned.